# cant pass the value from data using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

this is very frustrating, 2 hours passed and still can't get it working.

I just want to test on how to pass a value to my method using ajax.
Code:

Javascript

```
$('#form-payment').submit(function () {

        var request = $.ajax({
          url: "<?php echo site_url(array('home', 'update_credit_card')); ?>",
          type: "POST",
          data: 'someNumber=12'
        });

        request.done(function(data) {
            console.log('boom' + data);
        });

        request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            console.log('error' + textStatus);
            //print_r(jqXHR);

        });


    });
```

PHP

```
function update_credit_card()
{
    var_dump($_POST['someNumber']);//returns NULL value
    $somenumber = $_POST['someNumber'];

    if ($somenumber == '12') {
        print "Number is 12";
    } else {
        print "Number is not 12";
    }
}
```

The code is very simple but for the life of me can't get it to work. T_T.

Badly need help.

Comment: are you seeing 'error' in that it is going to request.fail, or are you getting 403 forbidden or 500 internal server error or what

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use like this.

```
var values={};
values['arg1'] = 1;
values['arg2'] = 2;

$.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url:'....',
  data: values,
  success:function(){}
});
```

Comment: still can't pass the value to my method (php). the $_POST always return NULL.